# Block & unblock user using XMPP in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp

I have reviewed so many blogs and sites for Block and unblock users using XMPP in Swift.
But, none of the examples has worked for me.
Anyone having snippet code then please share with me.
Thank you.

```
func blockUser(userJID: String) {
   let privacyList = XMPPPrivacy(dispatchQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
    privacyList?.activate(xmppStream)
    privacyList?.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)

     let privacyElement = XMPPPrivacy.privacyItem(withType: "jid", value: userJID, action: "deny", order: 0)
    XMPPPrivacy.blockIQs(privacyElement)
    XMPPPrivacy.blockMessages(privacyElement)
    XMPPPrivacy.blockPresence(in: privacyElement)
}
```

Comment: This is totally depended on your implementation. So just post what you have tried what is not working. Also ask for code will get your question downvoted since it is frowned up.

Comment: I have posted the code with a question. Now you can check and let me know where I am making mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [XEP 0191](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0191.html) for blocking functionality.

Code(Swift 3.0) :

```
     //Block / Unblock User

    var xmppBlocking: XMPPBlocking?
```

Add Block user and Unblock user

```
//Blocking Managment
    self.xmppBlocking = XMPPBlocking()
    self.xmppBlocking!.autoRetrieveBlockingListItems = true
    self.xmppBlocking!.autoClearBlockingListInfo = true;
    self.xmppBlocking!.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
    self.xmppBlocking!.activate(self.xmppStream)
    self.xmppBlocking?.retrieveBlockingListItems()

    xmppBlocking?.blockJID(user.jid) 
    xmppBlocking?.unblockJID(user.jid)



extension BlockListVC : XMPPBlockingDelegate{

        public func xmppBlocking(_ sender: XMPPBlocking!, didBlockJID xmppJID: XMPPJID!){
           //Successfully blocked
        }

        public func xmppBlocking(_ sender: XMPPBlocking!, didNotBlockJID xmppJID: XMPPJID!, error: Any!){
            if(error is NSError){
                //print error message
            }
        }

        public func xmppBlocking(_ sender: XMPPBlocking!, didReceivedBlockingList blockingList: [Any]!) {
            //Received blocked list in this delegate method
        }

   public func xmppBlocking(_ sender: XMPPBlocking!, didUnblockJID xmppJID: XMPPJID!) {

    }

    public func xmppBlocking(_ sender: XMPPBlocking!, didNotUnblockJID xmppJID: XMPPJID!, error: Any!) {
        if(error is NSError){

        }
    }
  }
```